# How can I access the raw request in rails and re-instantiate the request later in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I want to access the request object before a file upload gets converted into a tempfile and add it to a queue to be processed later, mainly because IO objects can't be marshaled or serialized. How can I do this?

I'll also need to "redo" the request at later point. At what point in the rails request lifecycle would I hook into to do this?

Comment: upload is handled by nginx / apache if deployed properly. SO what i suggest is just reading the file and serializing / marshaling content. So working with value. I think there is much more simple solution to what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how feasible this is, but I would use rack middleware.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I left the code examples in my answer (doesn't seem to work well in comments

Comment: I'm glad it worked OK for you and thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Code example, in routes.rb:

```
post 'incoming_email' => Proc.new { |env|
  RequestCache.create!(
    data: env['rack.input'].read,
    content_type: env['CONTENT_TYPE'],
    content_length: env['CONTENT_LENGTH']
  )

  [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['OK']]
}
```

and in the model:

```
class RequestCache < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :data, :content_length, :content_type

  def params
    Rack::Request.new({
      'rack.input' => StringIO.new(data),
      'CONTENT_LENGTH' => content_length,
      'CONTENT_TYPE' => content_type
    }).POST
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just to do this you don't do something complicated like that.

If you want to do upload in the background process, you could simply use [delayed_paperclip](https://github.com/jstorimer/delayed_paperclip). This gem use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and process upload, resize, send to s3 (if you want) in the background process.